# jquery carousel not functioning properly in Chrome or any webkit browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I made a infinite carousel from scratch into a plugin with jquery. It works fine in Firefox but it works partially in Chrome, i.e. elements disappear as I slide the carousel.

Please view my codes here (it was too long to paste it): http://jsfiddle.net/HkTks/2/

Compare the carousel with Firefox and Chrome.

Why is Chrome behaving like that?

Many thanks​

Comment: The image referenced in the fiddle is 404ing for me.

Comment: @Jonathan Rowny: I have updated the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HkTks/2/ So images should be ignoredr now. Please help me... :)

Comment: definitely seems to be a webkit issue, Safari craps out as well... for once, IE works!

Comment: @JonathanRowny: Thanks for your help... lol. Yeah I also find it funny, I was obliged to take IE side against my own dignity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this may be a webkit bug. Looks like somehow the anchor element accidentally inherited absolute positioning rather than relative.

Seeing the style of `.iconList a` to include `position: relative;` and removing `top:0` seemed to fix it for me.

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HkTks/4/